# Using t-test to check the difference between a sample and subsample?

Tags: t-test, sample, subsampling

I have a large dataset and I want to check if there is any difference between the whole sample and the subsample.
For example, I'm checking the difference in the age of patients in the whole sample and the age of patients with cancer (subsample).

Comment: For the t-test the two samples should not be overlapping.

Comment: ¿Is there a reason you cannot look at t-test comparing the 2 subsamples:  those with and without cancer?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=t+test+subsample) for more posts about this issue if you like.